# Firebase messaging ServieWorkerGlobalScope error on init

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to connect to the firebase db and create a class for messaging but for some reason I get `ReferenceError: self is not defined` when initializing the fireabase app.

```
import app from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/messaging";

const options = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

class Firebase {
    constructor() {
        app.initializeApp(options);

        this.messaging = app.messaging();
    }
}

const FirebaseApp = new Firebase();

export default FirebaseApp;
```

Full error is as follows:

```
/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.cjs.js:2110
if (self && 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope' in self) {
^
ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

If I remove `this.messaging=...` from `constructor()` then the error goes away.